# How do I lose the white space after p tag in table

Tags: html, css

I have a table with names of members. I have the data with the name and then elements, i.e. current rank, title, since with the company etc. I would like them to appear right below without any space, typically seen after a `p` tag.  I've read elsewhere here and other places on solutions, I've tried one that does not seem to offer the effect I need.

The CSS of `line-height: 5px; font-size: 5px;` I've modified to 5 from the suggested 14. I saw a change, but not sure on how far can I go, to zero? Then, I need to modify the font size of the elements in the grids with the name bigger than the other elements, currently this seems to work. Does the second item in the CSS (`font-size: 5px;`) conflict with this?

The last issue is when I resize the browser to small, the mobile site initiates and the text stays the same size and wraps.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table td {
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

table td p {
  line-height: 5px;
  font-size: 5px;
}

#first {
  font-size: 14pt;
}

#second {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

#third {
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="first">Tom Johns</p>
        <p id="second">Test Test</p>
        <p id="third">Life Member 1912</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id="first">Bob Jones</p>
        <p id="second">Past Chief</p>
        <p id="third">Member Since 1923</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are your cells always of different font sizes? Btw, IDs should only be used once.

Comment: No, but in this case yes. I want to make the persons name larger than the other elements.  Thanks for the info on the ID's, was not aware of that.

Answer (score 3):

```css
p {
  
  padding: 0;
}

table{
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border:thin black solid;
}

table td {
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

table thead tr th{
  border-bottom:thin black solid;
  padding: 5px;
}


table tbody tr td{ /* give padding as per your need */
  border-bottom:thin black solid;
  padding: 5px;
}

table td span {
  display:block;
  line-height:1.2;
}

.first {
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.second {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.third {
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0">
  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading 1</th>
      <th>Heading 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody align="center">
    
  
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="first">Tom Johns</span>
        <span class="second">Test Test</span>
        <span class="third">Life Member 1912</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="first">Bob Jones</span>
        <span class="second">Past Chief</span>
        <span class="third">Member Since 1923</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="first">Tom Johns</span>
        <span class="second">Test Test</span>
        <span class="third">Life Member 1912</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="first">Bob Jones</span>
        <span class="second">Past Chief</span>
        <span class="third">Member Since 1923</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead of `id` use `class` to give multiple style.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked!  This also fixed the table text responsiveness.  Before, the spacing was all off, now it resizes to fit the smaller screen.

Comment: I have to move the data around, ie the peoples names (and titles etc...) from time to time (when someone leaves) and typically the code is not together (arranged by rows), but in this arrangement it makes it easier to move the data.  I know it's not the correct way of doing things.

Comment: .third {
  font-size: 10pt;           padding-bottom: 10px; }    I need to have some space between the rows, but not between the elements, will this achieve that?

Comment: @lumio. I have removed p tag and put span tag which is inline element. and gave line-height for equal spacing (top & bottom) between inline elements. as there is no other block level element in span tag. that's why I can use span as block level element, as It has to obey XTML rule.

Comment: @Dennis. Instead of giving padding to particular class , you can give padding to `td`. I have updated my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: The first answer was much better, the second just added lots of stuff I don't need, ie headers, borders etc....    I don't need padding after every `td`, in every table, thanks for the help you solved it the first time.  Thanks!!!, d

Comment: ohkk.. You can change CSS as per your need. Good Luck.